# How to deal with legacy monster?

Tags: php, refactoring

I am working on a project (CRM for large company in my country) that is about 10 years old and the code is a total mess. Let me point some of the major problems:

- **There is no framework used**. As far as I know 10 years ago there was
  some CMS system (with already messy code) that has evolved into CRM.
- Dozens developers have worked on this project, thus you can spot
  anomalies like **3 different connections to database**.
- **There is no concept of a model or DBAL.** Everything is done straight
  with PDO object wrapped in some methods that sit in a gigantic classes. I think the Mount Everest of our project is class with 16 000 lines of code.
- As we have no framework pinned, every logic is either in "controller"
  which is just i.e. `clients.php` file or in those gigantic classes that just acts like a namespace. A few days ago I had to make a
  **decision between spending at least 10 days** trying to understand the
  business logic inside one of controllers, so I can extract a method that I was in need (thus probably breaking all module if I wanted to stay DRY) **or using curl to log into my
  application**, call file programmatically and profit. Quess what I have
  chosen.
- **And the icing on the cake is eval**. Last Friday I have found that in one of our "controllers" we have loop through `$_POST` and inside body of that loop there is an eval. So you can type `rm -rf /` or fetch all customers from database, basically everything you want.

Of course there are no tests whatsoever. I have barely one year of experience but I think it wouldn't be professional to throw more crap cause everything is crap already because of it. I have a good understanding of how major PHP frameworks works, and a few patterns they use.

I have tried implementing a basic FrontController and routing so I can drop `controller.php-pattern` and make a class-based heaven, but I was confused weather providing extra complexity to this code wouldn't make it more messy, cause suddenly half of things will be behaving differently.

I want to point out that I am not complaining. My knowledge is now enough to improve this code, and I am the only one that cares, so I this is why I am asking this question here to get some hints.

Could you please give me any tips of how I can improve this code a little? What would you do in this kind of situation aside from packing your stuff and leaving the company?

Thank you in advance for any tips & tricks.

Comment: Nuke it. Start from scratch.

Comment: I wish I knew the business logic in a depth that would allow me to do this. I hoped that maybe there are some techniques or principles that I can apply to make things better without nuking it.

Comment: @nogad:  What world do you live in?  Rewriting something from scratch usually leads to disaster.  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html  Worse, the time frame will kill you.  OP has a ten year old system; probably 30 man-years invested.  Let's assume those coders were just awful and were only 30% efficient with their time.  So...  ten man-years to recode assuming everything else is fine.   You personally can't do that.  A team of 5 takes 2 years to do that.  Nobody can afford to do as you suggest in practice.

Comment: well if a 16 year old blog post says so, it must be true;)

Comment: @nogad: Those rules that Newton gave us about physics... they're 300 years old.  Can't possibly apply now, right? Nah.

Comment: most dont apply at the quantum level, so yeah we actually do new learn new things as time goes on.

Answer (score 1):

i think the biggest problem, or the first task is a list, of things you can do with this thing!

Think about this stuff, maybe you need only 50% of the whole functionality, this is the start of every legacy-refactory i do.

Then you need a concept, maybe a ORM that fits best, or a complete Framework that provides most of the functions you need.

Make some sketches of the Objects, and how they work, and comunicate with the others.

Here is a great video that helped me alot! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7v9ehGsPm1s

Good luck!